# App crashes on making a new intent. NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, android-intent, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to navigate to a fragmentactivity with a button click but my app crashes on the line it creates the intent. Can anyone help me figure out why? The activity I am navigating too is in the same package and I believe it is correctly recorded in the manifest.

Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.indigohate"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.indigohate.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.indigohate.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.indigohate.GCMIntentService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.indigohate" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.indigohate" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.UserRegister"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_register" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.RideRequest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_ride_request" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.TimePickerFragment"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_time_picker_fragment" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.SearchForOffersActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_results_list" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.LoadingScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_loading_screen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.LostPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_lost_password" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.RideOfferActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_ride_offer" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.StartRideActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_start_ride" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.StopRideActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_stop_ride" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.CalendarActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_calendar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.ProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.MakeCommentActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_make_comment" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.PaymentInformation22Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_payment_information" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.RideHistoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_ride_history" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.AllRidesListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_all_rides_list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.RideDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_ride_detail" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.SearchRideActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_ride" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.PaymentInformationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register_payment" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.SubmitPaymentActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_submit_payment" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.JoinedRideDetail"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_joined_ride_detail" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.PaymentConfirmationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_payment_confirmation" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.ExistingOfferOrRequestActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_existing_offer_or_request" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.SearchForRequestsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_results_requests" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.UserProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_profile" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my code from the activity with the navigating button

```
package com.indigohate;



import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ProfileActivity extends Activity {

    public String userdataResult;
    public String profileIdentifier = "profile";
    public String uid;
    public static final String EXTRA_UID = "com.indigohate.extra.UID";
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "WheelsharePrefsFile";

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.PROFILE";

    private void asyncGetProfileData()
    {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        uid = settings.getString("UID", "Invalid");
        ServerRequestObject getProfileData = new ServerRequestObject();
        getProfileData.setUrl("http://172.9.69.232/wheelshare/profile.php?id=" + uid);
        ServerAsyncTask getProfile = new ServerAsyncTask();
        try{
            String str = getProfile.execute(getProfileData).get();
            String[] userdataLines = str.split(",");

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

            EditText inputFirstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textview_first_name); 
            EditText inputLastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textview_last_name);
            EditText inputStreet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textview_address);
            EditText inputCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textview_city);
            EditText inputState = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textview_state);
            EditText inputZip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textview_zip_code);

            inputFirstname.setText(userdataLines[2]);
            inputLastname.setText(userdataLines[3]);
            inputStreet.setText(userdataLines[4]);
            inputCity.setText(userdataLines[5]);
            inputState.setText(userdataLines[6]);
            inputZip.setText(userdataLines[7]);

        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        asyncGetProfileData();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.profile, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void paymentInfoClick(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentInformationActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("LAST_ACTIVITY", profileIdentifier);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void rideHistoryClick(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RideHistoryActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void saveChangesClick(View view)
    {
        //updateContact();
        //asyncUpdateContact();
        Log.d("USER", "before intents");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, UserProfileActivity.class);
        Log.d("USER", "inbetween intents");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onClickMakeCommentButton(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MakeCommentActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }




}
```

This is my log cat

```
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at com.indigohate.ProfileActivity.saveChangesClick(ProfileActivity.java:94)
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     ... 11 more
06-01 02:15:07.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5387): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.indigohate.UserProfileActivity
```

If anyone could help me it would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you recently update your Adt ? then there might be a chance for this problem.

Try going to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export and ensure Android Private Libraries are checked for your project and for all other library projects you are using

Comment: This was exactly the issue. Thanks