# How to fix NoClassDefFoundError in twitter4j using Android Studio?

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, twitter4j, android-studio

I want to integrate my project with Twitter. So, I'm using the twitter4j for this. And I'm using gradle to manage the dependencies.

Currently, I am facing this issue:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder
```

I've googled and find a solution, that is to change the name of "lib" folder to "libs", but this is for Eclipse. How can I fix this issue in Android Studio?

Thank you!

Comment: can you post some code or a sample project with it or link to a repo?

Comment: see my answer here .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16871247/931982

Comment: I am not using Eclipse. I am using AndroidStudio (IntelliJ)

Comment: are you using gradle?

Comment: Yeah! I am using gradle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your build.gradle, add the following in the dependencies section:

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar', 'libs/twitter4j.jar')
```

or if you want to automatically add all jars in the libs directory:

```
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: "*.jar")
```

You might need to run this on the command line:

```
./gradlew clean
```

Comment: Thank you! I fix this issue by running my gradlew with the clean parameter. ps: I am getting the dependencies from the maven repository. So I don't have any jar hard downloaded in my project.

Comment: Please describe, how to do this in eclipse.